# HowTo connect FS Minifilter Driver and my application on Vista & Win7?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, driver, interaction

Here what I have:

- *the user application* - it's MSVC project, service, written on C++ with small Boost & STL (app are using hooks to get users actions)
- *the driver* - it's a FS Minifilter Driver, that monitors USB mount/umount actions, and file movements

**Problem**: On XP, this two guys works great together, but when I'm started to port them on Vista & Win7 systems, the troubles rised quickly.

- driver doesn't installing, because it's not signed
- hooks are not working, because in Vista and above servicies are placed to the different session, and unable to interact with user session (f*ck!)...
- UAC - that doesn't gave access from my application to driver when it's ON, and so, and so...

**But**: I just want to hear, is there realy possible to connect driver and user application on Vista & Win7 with UAC-is-on, and if it's possible, what are conditions must be to perform this interaction (for example, driver must be signed or maybe something else...)?

Great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your driver should expose a virtual device for the user-mode application to open and interact with (often via IOCTLs).

This is completely independent of the filesystem device layers you are already working with.

When your driver creates this new virtual device, it can set permissions to allow any user to open it, only elevated admins, etc.

---

As a final note, the things you mentioned (monitoring mount, unmount, and MoveFile) are already built into Windows.  I don't know why you are writing a driver when you could use `WM_DEVICECHANGE` (for mount/unmount) and the `FindFirstChangeNotification`/`ReadDirectoryChangesW` and/or NTFS logs for MoveFile detection.

Comment: Can you support me with URLs/docs regarding the theme you are talking ("This is completely independent of the filesystem device layers you are already working with.")? Just for now, I don't clearly understand, what you are talking about. I would be inordinately grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can install unsigned drivers if you set the option on boot (google for it, can't remember how it's done). Using hooks to get user action is never a good idea. Use IPC. IIRC you can set a Desktop flag (SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS) when calling CreateService that tells the service it can interact with the desktop.
If you want to get notifications about USB mount/umount why don't you use system events, and for file modifications FindFirstChangeNotification (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: `SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_DESKTOP` gets you a desktop, but it's not the desktop used by the logged-in user IIRC.

Comment: "You can install unsigned drivers if you set the option on boot" (You are talking about switching OS to unsigned driver loading mode, turning UAC and other methods, if I get you right) But I'm working with the commercial version, so any system modifications will not be considered, and so I have to find leagal way to run driver with application on Vista & Win7...